# Cannot change printer name (WERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: networking, windows, printing

I am having MAJOR problems trying to network-share a printer I have connected to my Ubuntu machine (the rest of the machines on the network are all various versions of Windows).  I've been tangling with SAMBA and made some progress:  when trying to "Add Printers" from the Windows machines, they can actually see it when doing a network search.  However, Windows invariably asks for a driver ("The server for the printer does not have the correct printer driver installed..."), and then when I select one, it delivers the error message "Windows cannot connect to the printer.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly..."

I've done some research and I found that often this is due to the printer not being "named correctly":  using *enumprinters*, it has \LOCALHOST instead of the appropriate name.  The suggested fix is to rename the printer using *setprintername* (rpcclient).  However, I cannot do this:  I always get a WERR_ACCESS_DENIED error.

Additional research on rectifying THAT issue suggests "granting" oneself the appropriate privileges (*SePrintOperatorPrivileges*, using *net...user...rpc rights grant*)...but I cannot do that either:  I receive a "Failed to privileges for [user] (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)" message.  What the heck am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated, as this is a critical feature for me.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this Help?
[Sharing Printers With Windows PCs](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-and-Windows-Shared-Printing/sharing_with_windows.html)

Comment: Hello @ECarterYoung...thanks for your suggestion!  In all the research I'd been doing, it suggested that it wasn't a CUPS issue, but a SAMBA one.  Turns out they may have been correct:  I had to look in multiple places to piece all of this together, but I'm leaving it in case someone else has a similar question:

Comment: Out of Respect for Other Readers, tell us what you did to fix it by posting an answer then "Answering your own Question."

Comment: Sorry @ECarterYoung!  I tried posting it, but I only now found out that it failed (I'm also having browser issues, so that may be the cause).  I'm trying to repost it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this took research from multiple sites/pages.  I'm finding out that network printing using SAMBA in a mixed Ubuntu-Windows environment can be a complex affair, and this may not solve everyone's issues...but if your symptoms are the same, you can give this solution a shot.  (For all coding below, substitute your computer name for "computername" and your Ubuntu login name for "username", etc.)

When trying to add a networked/shared printer connected to an Ubuntu machine to a Windows client (so you can print from the Windows machine), the error message from Windows given above ("Windows cannot connect to the printer.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly...") may indicate that the **printer name** being reported by the Ubuntu machine is incorrect.  Windows appears to be very finicky about the name of networks and network resources.  From the terminal, using the command *rpcclient localhost*, then *enumprinters*, you may see output like this:

> rpcclient $> enumprinters
>     flags:[0x800000]
>     **name:[\LOCALHOST]**
>     description:[\LOCALHOST\HP-SuperJet-10,HP SuperJet 10,Hewlett-Packard HP >SuperJet 10]
>     comment:[Hewlett-Packard HP SuperJet 10]

Notice that the name field only contains "\LOCALHOST\"...this is incomplete; your printer name should also be in the brackets (in this case, "\LOCALHOST\HP-SuperJet-10").

The suggested solution is to use the command *setprintername* in rpcclient, but that may get you the error WERR_ACCESS_DENIED instead of WERR_INVALID_PRINERNAME.  This would seem to indicate that you as a user lack the permissions to make system-printer changes.  But after going through a lot of rigamarole trying to give myself the rights (e.g., using *SePrintOperatorPrivileges*) and getting additional errors (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED), I checked (*net rpc rights list -S Computername -U Username*) and found that I had *already* been set up with those rights!  This is what let me know something else was wrong.

The solution I found is to add a line to the Samba configuration file in the **[global]** section.  From the terminal window, type *gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf*

The line to add is:

> *force user = username*

Save your changes, close the gedit program, and then in the terminal window, restart the necessary services:

> *sudo service smbd restart*
>   *sudo service nmbd restart*

That should enable/enforce your permissions to change the printer name.  Enter *rpcclient localhost* to go back to the rpcclient.  Now, here's another catch I found:  For the *setprintername* command it seems you have to enter the printer name **TWICE**...simply entering *setprintername = HP-SuperJet-10* didn't work; after testing and failing again, an *enumprinters* check in rpcclient showed that the printer name STILL only showed "\LOCALHOST\".  (I'm guessing here, but it may be because that's the proper syntax for the *setprintername* command).  Enter:

> *setprintername = yourprintername yourprintername*

For me, "yourprintername" was "HP-SuperJet-10."  An *enumprinters* command this time should show something like this:

> rpcclient $> enumprinters
>         flags:[0x800000]
>         **name:[\\LOCALHOST\HP-SuperJet-10]**
>         description:[\LOCALHOST\HP-SuperJet-10,HP SuperJet 10,Hewlett-Packard HP SuperJet 10]
>         comment:[Hewlett-Packard HP SuperJet 10]

If you can see the proper printer name appended to the end of LOCALHOST in the name field, you've done it.  I found that when applying this fix, my Windows machines can even see the printer on the network whenever I attempt to "add a printer" from them.

Further notes:  this solution has only worked so far with me on Windows Vista machines.  Windows 7 appears to be giving me different error messages, which will almost certainly require a different solution.  Wish me luck!